# Nuxt: Inside a plugin, how to add dynamic script tag to head?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, head, gtag.js

I'm trying to build a Google Analytics plugin to Nuxt that will fetch tracking IDs from the CMS. I am really close I think.

I have a plugin file loading on client side only. The plugin is loaded from `nuxt.config.js` via the `plugins:[{ src: '~/plugins/google-gtag.js', mode: 'client' }]` array.

From there the main problem is that the gtag script needs the UA code in it's URL, so I can't just add that into the regular script object in `nuxt.config.js`. I need to get those UA codes from the store (which is hydrated form `nuxtServerInit`.

So I'm using `head.script.push` in the plugin to add the gtag script with the UA code in the URL. But that doesn't result in the script being added on first page load, but it does for all subsequent page transitions. So clearly I'm running `head.script.push` too late in the render of the page.

But I don't know how else to fetch tracking IDs, then add script's to the head.

```js
// plugins/google.gtag.client.js with "mode": "client
export default ({ store, app: { head, router, context } }, inject) => {
    // Remove any empty tracking codes
    const codes = store.state.siteMeta.gaTrackingCodes.filter(Boolean)

    // Add script tag to head
    head.script.push({
        src: `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${codes[0]}`,
        async: true
    })
    console.log('added script')

    // Include Google gtag code and inject it (so this.$gtag works in pages/components)
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments)
    }
    inject('gtag', gtag)
    gtag('js', new Date())

    // Add tracking codes from Vuex store
    codes.forEach(code => {
        gtag('config', code, {
            send_page_view: false // necessary to avoid duplicated page track on first page load
        })

        console.log('installed code', code)

        // After each router transition, log page event to Google for each code
        router.afterEach(to => {
            gtag('event', 'page_view', { page_path: to.fullPath })
            console.log('afterEach', code)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: If you look at the [nuxt-community/google-tag](https://github.com/nuxt-community/google-gtag/blob/master/lib/module.js) repo, it uses a module to do the script push because modules are built before plugins.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yeah that's actually where I got this from. So I need a plugin and a module then? It's not possible to do this just as a plugin? I'm not sure if a module can get access to the store either.

Comment: Indeed! The module will fire earlier in the life cycle than the plugin will, allowing you to inject into the head pre-compile whereas the plugin executes post-compile pre-bundle, which is most likely why you have this issue.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy thanks. Any tips on how I can access store in a module?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you found a solution for that?

Comment: @PhilippS. just posted the solution, thanks for the prompt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work and we use it in [production here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/funkhaus/stackhaus/master/plugins/google-gtag.client.js).

Code as of this writing looks like this:

```js
export default ({ store, app: { router, context } }, inject) => {
    // Remove any empty tracking codes
    let codes = _get(store, "state.siteMeta.gaTrackingCodes", [])
    codes = codes.filter(Boolean)

    // Abort if no codes
    if (!codes.length) {
        if (context.isDev) console.log("No Google Anlaytics tracking codes set")
        inject("gtag", () => {})
        return
    }

    // Abort if in Dev mode, but inject dummy functions so $gtag events don't throw errors
    if (context.isDev) {
        console.log("No Google Anlaytics tracking becuase your are in Dev mode")
        inject("gtag", () => {})
        return
    }

    // Abort if we already added script to head
    let gtagScript = document.getElementById("gtag")
    if (gtagScript) {
        return
    }

    // Add script tag to head
    let script = document.createElement("script")
    script.async = true
    script.id = "gtag"
    script.src = "//www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js"
    document.head.appendChild(script)

    // Include Google gtag code and inject it (so this.$gtag works in pages/components)
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
    function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments)
    }
    inject("gtag", gtag)
    gtag("js", new Date())

    // Add tracking codes from Vuex store
    codes.forEach(code => {
        gtag("config", code, {
            send_page_view: false // Necessary to avoid duplicated page track on first page load
        })

        // After each router transition, log page event to Google for each code
        router.afterEach(to => {
            gtag("event", code, { page_path: to.fullPath })
        })
    })
}
```

If not in a plug-in, this was a good read on how to load 3rd party scripts: [How to Load Third-Party Scripts in Nuxt.js](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-load-third-party-scripts-in-nuxt-js/)

Comment: This is also a good read: https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/how-to-load-third-party-scripts-in-nuxt-js/

Comment: the router transition should be an `event` not `config`: `gtag("event", "page_view", { page_path: to.fullPath })`.